# Why can parameters of a function be declared within a callback?

Tags: javascript

I know that test has two parameters, and that the cb parameter get filled with the callback parameters ('hello',undefined) - but I am having trouble wrapping my entire head around understanding this completely... Can anybody explain it in a way that makes sense?

```
const test = (addy,cb)=>{
    if (addy){
    cb('hello',undefined)
    }
}

test(true,(one,two)=>{
    console.log(one)
})
    // logs 'hello' to console
```

Comment: What exactly isn't making sense?

Comment: I guess what I am confused about is how initially, test takes in 2 parameters, yet when calling it, it takes in (true, (one,two)) - 2 parameters, except one of the parameters is split into 2 separate parameters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments:

> I guess what I am confused about is how initially, test takes in 2 parameters, yet when calling it, it takes in (true, (one,two))

What's going on, is you have nested functions. That is to say, `cb` is a callback (function) being sent to another function. You can think of it like this (even though this may not be valid syntax):

```
function test (addy,cb) {
    if (addy){
    cb('hello',undefined)
    }
}

test(true,function cb(one,two){
    console.log(one)
})
    // logs 'hello' to console
```

Or, even like this:

```
function test (addy,cb) {
    if (addy){
    cb('hello',undefined)
    }
}

function callback(one,two){
    console.log(one)
}    // logs 'hello' to console

test(true,callback) // notice, we really only have 2 arguments here
```

That is probably not proper syntax, but hopefully you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused because of this syntax. Please have a look into this , you have passed the second function as a headless function. so `cb` is the name of the function parameters are `one`, `two`

in my answer I have given a name for the function

> when you are calling the function test `first param: true` so `addy =
>   true` `second param: is the function` so `cb = function`

```js
const test = (addy,cb)=>{
    if (addy){
    cb('hello',undefined)
    }
}

test(true,(one,two)=>{
    console.log(one)
})

// this function is like cb is the name of the function

test(true, function(arg1, arg2){
  console.log('printing arg1 ' + arg1);
  console.log('printing arg2 ' + arg2);
})
```